# Switching from Space to Tab delimited in php

Tags: php, string

I have the following bit of code:

```
// Loop through returned data and write (append) directly to file
fprintf($fh, "%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s \n", "ID", "Name", "Description","Price","Merchant Category","URL","Image URL","Manufacturer","Manufacturer Part Number","Brand","Keywords","Quantity","Weight","UPC");

fprintf($fh, "\n");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 fprintf($fh, "%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s \n", $row['card_id'], $row['TitleConcat'], $row['description'], $row['price'], $row['Merchant'], $row['link'], $row['ImageURL'], $row['artist'], $row['Part'], $row['Brand'], $row['seo_keywords'], $row['quantity'], $row['Weight'], $row['UPC']);
```

As you can see it is using spaces. Is there  an easy way to switch the over to using tabs? I tried dooing this:

```
/ Loop through returned data and write (append) directly to file
fprintf($fh, "\t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \n", "ID", "Name", "Description","Price","Merchant Category","URL","Image URL","Manufacturer","Manufacturer Part Number","Brand","Keywords","Quantity","Weight","UPC");

fprintf($fh, "\n");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 fprintf($fh, "\t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \t \n", $row['card_id'], $row['TitleConcat'], $row['description'], $row['price'], $row['Merchant'], $row['link'], $row['ImageURL'], $row['artist'], $row['Part'], $row['Brand'], $row['seo_keywords'], $row['quantity'], $row['Weight'], $row['UPC']);

 }
```

Aparently off. o_O

Comment: replace spaces by `\t` (string should be in double quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to **output** tabs instead of spaces:

```
// Loop through returned data and write (append) directly to file
fprintf($fh, "%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s \n", "ID", "Name", "Description","Price","Merchant Category","URL","Image URL","Manufacturer","Manufacturer Part Number","Brand","Keywords","Quantity","Weight","UPC");

fprintf($fh, "\n");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 fprintf($fh, "%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s\t%-10s \n", $row['card_id'], $row['TitleConcat'], $row['description'], $row['price'], $row['Merchant'], $row['link'], $row['ImageURL'], $row['artist'], $row['Part'], $row['Brand'], $row['seo_keywords'], $row['quantity'], $row['Weight'], $row['UPC']);
```

Comment: did you really replaced all that space by hand? I hope not

Comment: Not one at a time, ha!  But I felt that the question was about how to **format output** using tabs instead of spaces, not how to modify a string in-place.

Comment: @aj: actually it seems the OP did the edit and wrote just that, what a  lost labour xd

Comment: Yeah, I just need it tabbed instead of space.

Answer (score 3):

```
str_replace(' ',"\t",$string);
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are no literal spaces in the values, then simply using [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) should cut it.

```
str_replace(' ', "\t", $line);
```

Comment: at least you changed $string with $line, some other people doens't do even that xD

Comment: O thanks. Just wondering, where do I put the str_replace ? Sorry, I am new to it all. I just need to get the two outputs to be tabbed. I do appreciated the help

Comment: @yes123, are you kidding me? You're going to downvote me cause you *think* I copied you. We answered at the same time. It's a simple problem with an obvious solution.

Comment: @Jason - it wasn't me that downvoted you. But judging by your reputation on the site, I would guess you know how things work here.  If your answer is almost exactly the same, and 2 minutes after, maybe you should consider adding more info/code to make your answer unqiue and have more value.  Or you could always delete your answer.

Comment: @yes123, I indeed know how SO works. I received no notification that an answer had be posted while entering my answer. As it included a link to the documentation, it was different and provided more information. So I left it. While I understand the annoyance of a competing similar answer, it's up to the community to decide which provides *more value* by voting. That's how SO works. And in this case, you had a concise, first answer. The community recognized that. So good work. Just mind the accusations.

Answer (score 1):

Might have misunderstood, but **if you want to change `fprintf`'s left justification character** to tab instead of space, you can use

```
%'\t-10s
```

instead of

```
%-10s
```

---

**If you want to replace the spaces between words with tabs**, just do what others suggested here, `str_replace()`:

```
$s="%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s \n";
fprintf($fh, str_replace(' ', "\t", $s), "ID", "Name", "Description","Price","Merchant Category","URL","Image URL","Manufacturer","Manufacturer Part Number","Brand","Keywords","Quantity","Weight","UPC");
```

**If you want to make this a bit nicer**, you can also use [`str_repeat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php), so you don't need such a long format string.

```
fprintf($fh, str_repeat("%-10s\t", 14)."\n", "ID", "Name", "Description","Price","Merchant Category","URL","Image URL","Manufacturer","Manufacturer Part Number","Brand","Keywords","Quantity","Weight","UPC");
```